# FB or SQL Server xpress: what is the best performance for a vb.net project?

Tags: sql-server-2008, firebird

I'm planning a new sistem which is going to use quite large datatables. I'm not sure about which database I ought to use: FireBird (v. 2.5) or SQL Server Express (v. 2008). Despite the limitations of the Express version of SQL, it seems to be more integrated with .NET. Otherwise, FB must to connect with .NET through an "not included" ODBC driver, and I dont' know if it would reduce performance. Anyway, FB seems to be more robust, reliable and not limited as a free version of SQLS. What should I know about this comparation?

Comment: There is a real, non-ODBC .NET provider for Firebird.

Comment: Try http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/

Answer (score 0):

As others said: for Firebird, you don't need to use an ODBC driver; there's a native .Net driver which is actively developed/maintained. See [the main Firebird site](http://www.firebirdsql.org)
Additionally, there's a DDX module that lets you integrate Firebird into the Visual Studio (all editions except Express) GUI (database connections etc)

Firebird pros:
 - no conscious built in limits/throttling. SQL Express apparently is limited to 1 GB and 1 physical processor [Wikipedia but I'm sure there's tons of MS documentation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_Server_Express)
 - scale out from local (embedded or listening on 127.0.0.1:3050) to separate Linux or Windows database server if your dbs get really big
 - active support community, paid support available
 - allows easy switchover to a Linux/Unix application/environment

Firebird cons:
 - SQL Server is more mainstream with .Net (more examples, tighter integration)
 - if you're not used to it you have to learn it. Applies to SQL Server as well, of course.

My opinion: if you're willing to learn, go with Firebird and make sure you properly tune the database, possibly with help from the Firebird mailing list (quite helpful).
If you want the easy (from an app dev point of view), mainstream .Net, possibly more expensive way, go with SQL Server Express and scale out to regular SQL Server.

Note: I do not have experience with large scale SQL Server or FB databases, just a happy Firebird user.